# eclipse ganymede erroneous red underlining

Tags: eclipse

i'm finding suddenly that eclipse, in a java project, is underlining references to uses of other class uses ive created in the same package.  for another reason i reinstalled it today and the red underlinings went away.  about an hour later, they popped up again.  all classes have the package membership declaration.

anyone seen this before?

Comment: Yes. At least I seem to have a problem where eclipse fails to understand the imports and thus underlines everything that was supposed to be imported. But it happens so rarely I've not tracked it through.

Comment: try using the refresh flag .ini file in the eclipse folder.It cleans up and refreshes the entire IDE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that your compilation is bad for one reason or another. To remedy this  I usually do the following in order until one works:

1. Do a project clean (this should force a compile)
2. Close and reopen the project.
3. Close and reopen Eclipse.

I hope this helps.

Comment: not sure if clean worked - i forgot to check the underlining was still there before i did a clean (busy) but it's good now. thanks.

Comment: it does work.  users reading this may want to use Alt-P N <return> as a shortcut.  I'm finding with my package it's re-red underlining quote a lot.